# How to Add Static Path in Python Coding in Flask?

Tags: flask, directory, static

I am developing some search engine type application. My Code is look like this:

```py
def bm25searcher(queri,pagi):
    folders = loadfolders("files-clean/")
    xieon =""
    #query = sys.argv[1]
    query=queri
    results=[]
    page = pagi
    if(pagi==""):
        page = 1

    for folder in folders:
        files = loadfiles("files-clean/"+folder+"/")
        for filegotten in files:
            x  = removeemptylines(readpdf("pdf/"+folder+"/"+filegotten.replace("txt","pdf")))
            #results.append(str(tfidf_cosine_similarity(query,"files-clean/"+folder+"/"+filegotten))+",""files-clean/"+folder+"/"+filegotten.replace("txt","pdf")+","+abstract(x))
            results.append(str(bm25_cosine_similarity(query,"files-clean/"+folder+"/"+filegotten))+"~"+"<table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\"><tr><td width=\"88%\">"+filegotten.replace("txt","pdf")+"</td><td width=\"12%\">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>"+abstract(x)+"</td><td><a href='"+"static/pdf/"+folder+"/"+filegotten.replace("txt","pdf")+"' target='_blank'>Read File</a></td></tr></table><br/>"+"~"+x)
    res = sorted(results,reverse=True)
    sentencebulk = ""
    for g in range (10*int(page)-10,10*int(page)):
            if int(g)<145:
                ming = res[g+1].split("~")
                xieon+=str(ming[1])
                sentencebulk = sentencebulk+" "+ming[2]+" "
    sio = wordclouder2(sentencebulk)
    return xieon+"</td><td rowspan=\"2\" width=\"100%\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">"+sio+"</td>"
```

---

My Flask Core Code Look Like This:

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="template/",static_folder="static/")

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    #return mainpage()
    return render_template("index.html")
@app.route('/tfidf/',methods=["POST", "GET"])
def tfidf():
    lig = ""
    page = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        lig = request.form["textfield"]
        page = request.form['search']
    return render_template("tfidf.html",output=str(tfidfx(lig,page)))


@app.route('/bm25/',methods=["POST", "GET"])
def bm25():
    lig = ""
    page = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        lig = request.form["textfield"]
        page = request.form['search']
    #return bm25x(lig,page)
    return render_template("bm25.html",output=str(bm25x(lig,page)))



    return xieon
# main driver function
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # run() method of Flask class runs the application
    # on the local development server.
    app.run()
```

---

I want the Code should return PDF Path in HTML from python coding as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/pdf/civil Appeal/somefile.pdf
```

But It is returning

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/bm25/static/pdf/civil Appeal/somefile.pdf
```

---

How can I modify this code in python coding html that it gives static path from base url, not from the page it opened.? `i.e url/static/`  not `url/page/static/`

I want to change bm25searcher readfile hyperlink via python programming, how do i insert static path in function with html.

The front end looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `url_for()` function to build the url

```
from flask import .., url_for

[..]

filename = f'pdf/{folder}/{filegotten.replace("txt", "pdf")}'
href = url_for( 'static', filename=filename )

[..]
```

and then

```
..
    '<a href="' +  href + '" target="_blank">Read File</a>'
..
```

have a look at this tutorial https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for.
what I did is. made a variable of url (hardcoded). `base_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/"`
Then added in link. Now it is working fine. Thanks.

But now i try this f-string, because without that, my code was giving direct output instead of  html for "url_for". in link it become `http://127.0.0.1:5000/bm25/url_for('static',filename='static/pdf/cat/1.pdf')`

Comment: check my update, i just forgot that you return hard coded html in `bm25searcher()` and there's no need to `jinja2` expressions `{{ ... }} `

Comment: @SbaStuff  if you think my answer had solved your issue plz consider giving it the green tick i appreciate that.